# Why console.dir () in Firefox gives the following results (UTF-8)?

Tags: javascript, firefox, utf-8, console

Let's say there is a code (UTF-8, with the Cyrillic alphabet)

```
var test = {name:'Съешь ещё этих мягких французских булок'};
console.dir(test.name);
console.dir(test);
```

Why in the console (FF 25.0) in the second case shows gibberish?
The system still does not insert pictures, so the image can be viewed only by reference https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYAcR.png

Comment: +1 for французцкие булки. Very delicious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most-likely a bug. `console.dir` seems to read only the lowest byte of each character if it reads a property:

```
function asciify(s){
    var i, r = [];
    for(i = 0; i < s.length; ++i){
        r.push(String.fromCharCode(s.charCodeAt(i) & 0xff));
    }
    return r.join("");
}

console.log(asciify('Съешь ещё этих мягких французских булок'));
```

However, when you use `console.dir` on a string, it seems to use `console.log`, which interprets non-ASCII symbols correctly. You should file a bug-report.